# How to add logging with session data in MVC CF app neatly?

Tags: model-view-controller, logging, coldfusion

At first I thought of subclassing Services and add logging calls around it, but but then there is no way to pass the 'current logged in user' to the service layer by parameter without modifying a lot of code.  Accessing the Session directly?  Doesn't seem right.  Session Facade?

Doing the logging in the Controller level would be easier.  I have no problem accessing the Session directly, but it wouldn't log if the service is invoked by other sources (e.g. Ajax? Flex?) other then the MVC app.

AOP?  Not sure how it'd help, but if it does pls enlighten me.

Thought? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of implementing logging functionality using ColdSpring's AOP functionality in the [ColdSpring Quickstart Guide](http://www.coldspringframework.org/coldspring/examples/quickstart/index.cfm?page=aop).  Logging is an excellent example of a good use for AOP.

As far as interacting with the session scope, I use a [Session Facade](https://gist.github.com/906496).  This will work with any scope.

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

<cfset variables.instance = {} />
<cfset variables.instance.scopename = '' />
<cfset variables.instance.scope = '' />

<cffunction name="init" returntype="scopeFacade" output="false" access="public">
    <cfargument name="scope" required="true" type="variablename" />
    <cfset variables.instance.scopename = arguments.scope />
    <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getscope" returntype="struct" output="false" access="private">
    <cfreturn structGet(variables.instance.scopename) />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="get" returntype="any" output="false" access="public">
    <cfargument name="key" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="default" required="false" type="string" />
    <cfset var scope = getscope() />
    <cfif structKeyExists(arguments,"default") and not structKeyExists(scope,arguments.key)>
        <cfreturn arguments.default />
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn scope[arguments.key] />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="set" returntype="void" output="false" access="public">
    <cfargument name="key" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="value" required="true" type="any" />
    <cfset var scope = getscope() />
    <cfset scope[arguments.key] = arguments.value />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="delete" returntype="void" output="false" access="public">
    <cfargument name="key" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfset var scope = getscope() />
    <cfif exists(arguments.key)>
        <cfset structDelete(scope,arguments.key) />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="exists" returntype="boolean" output="false" access="public">
    <cfargument name="key" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfreturn structKeyExists(getScope(),arguments.key) />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I suppose that proper locking is done somewhere on higher level. Otherwise I would recommend to add it into the listed methods.